# Point colors and facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hadley Wickham's "ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis" book has this example graph in chapter 7, where mean points for all three colors of z appear on each facet:

[image]

Here's the code provided by the book to make the graph:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = rnorm(120, c(0, 2, 4)),
    y = rnorm(120, c(1, 2, 1)),
    z = letters[1:3]
)


df_sum <- df %>%
    group_by(z) %>%
    summarise(x = mean(x), y = mean(y)) %>%
    rename(z2 = z)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_point(data = df_sum, aes(colour = z2), size = 4) +
    facet_wrap(~z)
```

Ideally, keeping the color name as z as opposed to renaming it to z2 should produce the same result:

```
df_sum <- df %>%
     group_by(z) %>%
     summarise(x = mean(x), y = mean(y))

df_sum <- df %>%
     group_by(z) %>%
     summarise(x = mean(x), y = mean(y))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_point(data = df_sum, aes(colour = z), size = 4) +
     facet_wrap(~z)
```

But doing so makes it so that only one colored point appears on each facet:

[image]

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

No, it should not produce the same result. As you use `facet_wrap` by variable `z`, you split the data for each facet panel, only plotting what belongs to a, b or c (your "incorrect" graph). By renaming `z` to `z2` you can keep the `facet_wrap` by `z` for the black points but still plot each coloured point in each panel (as in `df_sum` there is no variable `z` that `facet_wrap` would use).